# Vue CLI - Parsing nested data in component from local JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to render the following view from JSON with a Vue component:

[image: article inside a section]

**JSON:**

```
{
  "0": {
    "title": "Title0",
    "content": {
      "0": {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": false
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "title": "Title1",
    "content": {
      "0": {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": false
      },
      "1": {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": true,
        "imagePath": "../../Assets/images.sample.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And to parse that data I have written the following Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <section v-for="(data, index) in jsonTitle" :key="index">
      <h5>{{data.title}}</h5>
      <article v-for="(data, index) in jsonTitle" :key="index">
        <h6>{{data.content[0].text}}</h6>
        <img v-if="data.content[0].image === true" v-bind:src="data.imagepath" alt="">
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import json from "@/components/json/english.json";
  export default {
    name: "databox",
    data() {
      return {
        jsonTitle: json
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

I am definitely missing something in this code. I only get the 1st data of the second title. Please provide a Vue CLI solution rather than Vue.js, as I am new and don't possess much knowledge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, any time you have a list of data in your JSON, use an array instead of an object with numbered indexes.  For example:

```
const json = [
  {
    "title": "Title0",
    "content": [
      {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
...
```

I changed the name `jsonTitle` to `profiles`, imagining that this is some profile data.  It makes the template clearer to study, since you have two loops.  Each loop has its own index used as a key.  Here is how your component should look:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <section v-for="(profile, indexProfile) in profiles" :key="indexProfile">
      <h5>{{ profile.title }}</h5>
      <article v-for="(content, indexContent) in profile.content" :key="indexContent">
        <h6>{{ content.text }}</h6>
        <img v-if="content.image === true" :src="content.imagePath" alt="">
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import json from "@/components/json/english.json";
export default {
  name: "databox",
  data() {
    return {
      profiles: json
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

There was also a typo with `imagepath` instead of `imagePath`.  Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/puojqw1v/)

Comment: Thanks, for the solution Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the "JSON data" is received from the backend or you are forming it. If you are forming the JSON, instead of giving objects inside objects create an array of objects like below.

```
[
 {
    "title": "Title0",
    "content": [
      {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": false
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "title": "Title1",
    "content": [
      {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": false
      },
      {
        "text": "few text here",
        "image": true,
        "imagePath": "../../Assets/images.sample.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```